# Deduction error of template parameters of a template template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

I'm having issues when writing template members of a non template class, specfically when deducing template parameters of a template template argument.

The following code, minimal, illustrates my problem. I suspect there are at least two different problems down there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    list<int> l;

    template<template<class> class Iterable> 
    A(Iterable<int>& it);
};

template<template<class> class Iterable>
A::A(Iterable<int>& it) : l(list<int>())
{
    for(int i : it)
        l.push_back(i);
}

int main()
{
    list<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    A a(l);
    for(int i : a.l)
        cout << i << " ";
     cout << endl;

    A b = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for(int i : b.l)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Remarks : I really want to provide the definition out of class. I also want the prototype of the constructor of `A` to work with lists of ints, vectors of ints, as well as initializer list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect there are at least two different problems down there.

Correct: I see three different problems.

1) `std::list` needs **two** template parameter; the second is defaulted (`std::allocator<T>`, where `T` is the first template parameter); and also vectors, deques, sets, etc. requires more that a template parameter (some defaulted).

So `template<template<class> class>` doesn't match `std::list` and other STL containers.

To be more generic, I suggest something as

```
template <template <typename...> class Iterable, typename ... Ts> 
A (Iterable<int, Ts...> & it);
```

2) `A b = {1, 2, 3, 4};` doesn't work because you're calling a constructor with four arguments and you have only constructors with one argument. So you have to explicit the container with something as

```
A b = std::list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Given that you expect `std::initializer_list` as default container, if you accept to double the graphs (`{ { 1, 2, 3, 4 } }`, instead of `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`, to pass a single argument to the constructor) you can indicate `std::initializer_list` (or another container, if you prefer) as default `Iterable`.

I mean... if you declare the constructor as follows

```
   template <template <typename...> class Iterable = std::initializer_list,
             typename ... Ts> 
   A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it);
```

then you can initialize `b` as

```
   A b {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

3) the signature `Iterable<int, Ts...> & it`, in your template constructor, accept a l-value reference, so accept

```
list<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
A a(l);
```

but doesn't accept

```
A b = std::list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

because `std::list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}` is a r-value.

To solve this problem you can write a different constructor for r-value references but, in this case, I suspect that is acceptable simply modify the template construct to make it able to accept **const** l-value references

```
A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it); 
// .....................^^^^^
```

Bonus (Off Topic) suggestion: if you're interested in accepting STL containers, you can simplify your template constructor using the `l` constructor that accept a couple of iterators (`begin()`, `end()`), so

```
template <template <typename...> class Iterable, typename ... Ts>
A::A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it) : l{it.cbegin(), it.cend()}
 { }
```

or also

```
template <template <typename...> class Iterable, typename ... Ts>
A::A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it) : l{std::cbegin(it), std::cend(it)}
 { }
```

The following is your code modified

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct A
 {
   std::list<int> l;

   template <template <typename...> class Iterable = std::initializer_list,
             typename ... Ts> 
   A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it);
 };

template <template <typename...> class Iterable, typename ... Ts>
A::A (Iterable<int, Ts...> const & it) : l{std::cbegin(it), std::cend(it)}
 { }

int main ()
 {
   std::list<int> l {1, 2, 3, 4};
   A a(l);

   for (auto i : a.l)
      std::cout << i << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   A b {{1, 2, 3, 4}};

   for (auto i : b.l)
      std::cout << i << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: 1) Why do I need to explicitely specify the second template parameter in list, as I  don't need to write anything when I write list<int> l = {1, 2, 3 4}

Comment: 2) I don't understand why there is no implicite template parameter deduction with std::initializer_list on that matter

Comment: 3) Alright with the l-value : my bad, the code I wrote is not like the original. basicaly : const is the solution I use. As for the suggestion with begin() and end(), it is marvelously elegant, I'll keep this one. beside, it also wotks with ilitializer lists

Comment: Remark : the problem that still needs to be "solved" : I still want the line "A b = {1, 2, 3, 4};" to be accepted, preferably without writing a separated constructor with std::initializer_list as a parameter

Comment: @R.Absil - 1) when you write `std::list<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4}`, `l` is a `std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>`; so if you want match this type, you have to intercept the typename following the first one; you can write `template <template <typename...> class Iterable, typename T2> A (Iterable<int, T2> & it);` and, this way you can't match `std::initializer_list` (no additional defaulted typenames) and `std::set/std::multiset` (two additional defaulted typenames); so I suggest a variadic list that can intercept almost all (not `std::array`, because the second template parameter is a number).

Comment: @R.Absil - because `{1, 2, 3, 4}` can be used to initialize a lot of different types and the language doesn't give to `std::initializer_list` a priority. But I've found (I'm surprised that works) a way to solve the "problem that still needs to be solved"; not exactly as you asked but I suppose in an acceptable way. Give me some minutes and I modify the answer.

Comment: @R.Absil - answer modified.

Comment: Thanks for everything !